# What is the most efficient method to cut a 3-d object into n equal volume parts?

Tags: algorithms

Efficiency is defined as making the fewest cuts regardless of length for every n slices. The shape can be either a cylinder or rectangular prism but nothing else.

The cuts must be doable without lifting the knife. Only cuts that are either circular or straight are allowed.

The end pieces must be of equal volume but not necessarily the same shape - meaning they can be asymmetrical. "Slices" of cake that are handed out should be whole, not made up of different pieces or having cuts through them.

If you want, you may consider cutting the cake parallel, or not, to the top surface, meaning splitting it into layers. If you do this, ensure the final pieces are of equal volume, even if not surface area.